# Find all intersecting points between two multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The curves are described by $$(x,y)=(t^2,t+1), \, t \in R$$ and $$5x^2+5xy+3y^2-8x-6y+3=0$$ 
My idea is to transform the curve into $x=(y-1)^2 \leftrightarrow y^2-2y-x+1 = 0$. But how shall I go from here to find pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfies both equations? One thought is to let
$$g(x,y) = y^2-2y-x+1$$
$$h(x,y) = 5x^2+5xy+3y^2-8x-6y+3$$
Then consider the contour lines $g(x,y)=0$ and $h(x,y)=0$. If we geometrically can describe these contour lines and then find the union between them we are done. But I have no idea how to do that or if it's possible. Any idea? I don't want the answer to be given to me, just a hint should suffice.

Comment: Since the first curve tells you $x=t^2$ and $y=t+1$, what happens if you substitute these into the second curve?

Comment: Oh thanks, it got very simple after simplifying.